# Error when trying to type 'node start' MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, stack, mean

I'm attempting to learn the MEAN stack, and I have this error when I type node start

```
     npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
    npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 489 while parsing 
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "name": "meanauthapp",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "version": '
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

Below is in the package.json file that I generated and haven't touched using npm init and npm install NAMES --save. I have an app.js file that should work with setting a port to 3000 and variables to the required packages I installed

```
  {
  "name": "meanauthapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "meanauthapp",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "mongojs": "^2.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.8",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "author": "",
   "license": "ISC"
}
```

I'm unsure as to why the error is happening, thanks for any input!

Comment: Try using a JSON validator when you have these issues! https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma, so it's failing to parse the invalid JSON. Update your scripts property to:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app"
  },
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. Thank you for the help!